# MATLAB How to normalize image to zero and unit variance

Tags: matlab, mean, variance

I am trying to normalize an image to zero mean and unit variance.

My code:

```
X = imread('my_image');
X = X-mean(X(:));
X = X/std(X(:), 0, 1);
```

It seems the zero mean works but I get an error when trying to compute the variance. The last line gives me this error:

```
Error using var (line 59)
First argument must be single or double.

Error in std (line 32)
y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: As what Luis said, cast the image as `double` first before proceeding to subtract the mean, and then using `std`.  Otherwise what you have is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

- `std` only operates on `double` or `single` values (not on `uint8` for example). You should cast to `double` within `std`.
- You should also cast `X` to `double` in order to get more precise results in the subtraction (`mean` line) and the division (`std` line).

So: cast `X` to `double` initially, and then do the computations:

```
X = imread('my_image');
X = double(X);
X = X-mean(X(:));
X = X/std(X(:), 0, 1);
```